# random variables independent of itself

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Originally from Exercise 18 of Tao's blog: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682473.

Show that a random variable ${X}$ taking values in a locally compact, ${\sigma}$-compact metric space is independent of itself (i.e. ${X}$ and ${X}$ are independent) if and only if ${X}$ is almost surely equal to a constant.

Assume independence of itself, we get in particular that ${\bf P}(X = c) = 0$ or $1$ for any constant $c$. But then how do we use the condition of locally compact, $\sigma-$compact metric space to finish the argument?

Comment: There are *lots* of nonconstant random variables $X$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X=c)=0$ for all $c$, so you didn’t learn much. How would you handle this kind of set-up?

Comment: Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if for all sets $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$ in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, $$ P[X \in A, Y \in B] = P[X \in A] P[Y \in B].$$

Comment: @Alex: Yes, hence one direction gives ${\bf P}(X \in A) = [{\bf P}(X \in A)]^2$, which then gives ${\bf P}(X \in A) = 0$ or $1$ for any measurable $A$. But how does one proceed? And where does the condition of locally compact $\sigma$-compact state space come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint.

Considering events $X=c$ won't be enough, since you can have non-constant $X$ with $P(X=c)=0$ for all $c$, even on locally compact, $\sigma$-compact metric spaces.

Instead, let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be the measurable space on which $X$ is defined with $\mathcal{E}$ the Borel sets induced by the metric topology.  Consider that for every $B\in\mathcal{E}$, independence of X with itself gives:
$P(X\in B) \in \{0,1\}$, so you have this fact for much more than just singleton sets.

Now, how can this much stronger property make $X$ almost surely constant?

Consider the set of all open balls $B(x,1/n), x\in E, n\in\mathbb{N}$.  By the above, all of these balls have probability 0 or 1.

For every $x\in E$, because the balls are monotone decreasing in $n$, we either have (a) $P(B(x,1/n))=1$ for all $n$ or (b) $P(B(x,1/n))=0$ for all sufficiently large $n\geq n(x)$.  Is it possible that (b) holds for all $x$?  If it did, then $B(x,1/n(x))$ would be an open cover of $E$, and you could make use of $\sigma$-compactness to make a frankly unbelievable statement about $P(X\in E)$.  So, it seems certain that (a) holds for at least one $x$.  Could it hold for two distinct $x$? If not, you might be done.  I don't think you need local compactness here, but I might have missed some technical detail.